# How to write SQL query leftjoin?

Tags: mysql

with table like this I want to answer:

Given the `Employee` and `AnnualReviews` tables, write a query to return all employees who have never had a review sorted by HireDate. (Table link below)

Here is my query, kindly help to correction:

```
Select

LastName,
FirstName

from Employee a leftjoin AnnualReviews b ON a.`ID` = b.`EmpID`
where HireDate desc

Group by
ID
```

[employee & annual review][1]

[1]: [employee & annual review table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAw8L.jpg)

Comment: You don't seem to need the table Annual Reviews to solve this so why did you publish it?

Comment: This question no longer looks like the question I commented on - thereby invalidating the answer you accepted.- You should not evolve questions. For radical changes like this you should raise a new question.

Comment: Hi, I have already edited &  attach the table link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM employee
WHERE terminationdate IS NULL AND lastname LIKE ‘SMITH%’
ORDER BY lastname, firstname;
```